# How to horizontal align an image and text (home page menu)

Tags: css, menu, alignment

Here is my code, what I want is to line this in horizontal using only css.

```
    <div id="menu">


    <img class="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/148/56/">
    <span class="fleft">
    <ul class="tab">
    <li> <a href>home </a> </li>
    <li> <a href> about us </a> </li>
    <li>  <a href>products </a> </li>
    <li> <a href> services </a> </li>
    <li> <a href> blog </a> </li>
    <li>  <a href>contact us </a> </li>
    </span>
    </div>
```

and the css

and here is the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/5h9qmzou/

Comment: What  if you go with horizontal line? It should be horizontal not vertical. Wrong title

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display:inline` for `li`, use `display: block` or remove the style completely.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h9qmzou/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Right now it is `horizontal` only `margin` you have to provide to give space in between. And to make `vertical` 1 below other you have to add `display:block` instead of `display:inline`.

```
li
{
display: block;
}
```

It will work for you.